# What programming language should I use for my dream app

Tags: android, web

So, I have enrolled my software engineering course and I am really excited about it. In fact, I have already a project in mind but the problem is I don't know where or how to start, what are the tools that I am going to need, what language should I use and etc.

Well, here's how my dream project would be. I want to create an app that will help people set an appointment to their doctors. Of course, there are two users. One is for the patient and one's for the doctor. Now the patient can search a doctor who is in our database. That patient can set an appointment to the doctor in his desired date but it requires approval of the doctor first.

Now for the doctor. If the user is a doctor and wants to register in our app so that he can put his name in the database. The doctor can view the patients who sets an appointment in the date selected and can approve or disapprove patients. The doctor can also add a note if ever he/she disapprove the patients appointment request so that the doctor can explain why he can't attend on the specified date. If the doctor approves the set date of the patient, it will notify the patient that his doctor approves his requested date for check-up.

Now here's my questions:

1) **What programming tools should I use to create that app?** (Please specify the purpose of the tools you suggest)

2) **Is it better off responsive website rather than a mobile app**. (because I also want this app to work on desktop. :D)

3) **How complex is this app to make?** (We only have a span of 6 months to do an app.)

4) **Where can  find free tutorials?**

5) **Any tips you can suggest to make the development time faster and easier.**

That's all, Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.**

Comment: Questions 1 to 5, common answer: **Google for that!**.

Comment: For Android applications, use Android Studio and for your database, use Firebase and implement a connection between the two. I would also recommend you to read through CRUD or HTTP methods. You will find most common tutorials on YouTube about Login and Register which will give you basic ideas getting and posting methods of HTTP. Message me if you need more info or clarification. But I do recommend you do read through what Pirho has told you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Android Studio as Development tool, Java for coding, and Google Firebase for Database or Storage or Notification etc